# Separate fields for Users and admins in Django models.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a BooleanField in my models.py file.

I want it to be True for all Admins/Superusers by default, while I want it to be False for all other users by default.

I don't want to use if-else template tags in my html for this purpose, and I am hoping to get a more cleaner solution.

Something like:

```
field_name = models.BooleanField(
if author.is_superuser:
    default = True
else:
    default=False
)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Here the author is the author of the 'Post' which is the model class.

Edit 1: The user.is_superuser which I need is actually the author's user. I need to verify whether the author of a Blog post is a superuser or not, and then assign the default value for the Boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any notion of a "current user" in a model definition. But you do have access to the current user in your views (as `request.user`) so you can use it there to [pass the proper initial value for your field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

as an example (using function based view):

```
def myview(request, ....):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
    else:
        form = YourModelForm(initial={"field_name": request.user.is_superuser})
```

**EDIT**

> I don't need the user, but the author's user

What can I say ? **If you want better answers, [write better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** - you didn't put any context in your question, not even the relevan parts of your model.

This being said, model fields default values are only used in two cases: when creating a new instance, and when adding a new fields to an existing model.

In the first case, your `Article` or whatever model instance doesn't exist yet, so it cannot have an "author" yet. IOW the "author" is either the request user (most common case and very probably yours), or some other user you explicitely provide. In both cases you do have the right user instance at hand and my answer above applies (either as is or with some adaptation that you're suppoed to be able to do by yourself).

In the second case, that's something you deal with with a data migration, quite simply.

Comment: I don't need the user, but the author's user